# Can I use the Oxygene free command line compiler to develop open source code?

Tags: open-source, oxygene

I just downloaded the Oxygene free command line compiler, and tried to read the EULA, which I did not quite understand. While there was a section about compiled programs and redistributables, I did not really understand what it meant as it seemed by and large to talk about the actual package I downloaded and installed and had nothing to do with programs I compile using the compiler. I'm not sure as well if I can post the EULA here as it may also be subject to its own copyright, so I apologise for that inconvenience as well.

So can I use the compiler to write open source programs and libraries?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about EULA / legal issues, not programming or software development. See the [[help/on-topic]] for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not only write open source programs and libraries.

The compiler is free as in free beer: You may also get drunk with it. Meaning you are also allowed to develop (and sell) commercial applications build with the free command line compiler.

So have fun :)

Comment: THANK YOU! Finally, someone answered it! I had already believed that no one would answer this!